# Make toward or towards

Tags: word-usage

> (1) He made toward the library.
>   (2) He made towards the library.

Which one is correct?   If both are correct, which one sounds better or more natural?  Could you help me clarify it?

Comment: Neither example sentence sounds very correct, but we do sometimes say that someone [**makes for** something to mean that they head towards it, or aim towards it](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/make-for-something).

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think neither one is correct grammatically; however, it has nothing to do with whether you should use "toward" or "towards"; it has to do with the construction of the sentence.  It should read something like this:

> He made **his way** *toward* the library.
>
> He made **his way** *towards* the library.

Now that I have corrected your two sentences, I shall answer your question.  Both the prepositions "toward" and "towards" mean the exact same thing; they are merely variants.  "toward" is more common in American English than "towards" whereas "towards" is more common in British English than "toward"; therefore, both of your sentences are correct once you interpolate "his way" into them.

Happy New Year!  Take care and good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer.  That was a brilliant explanation and it helped me a lot.   Thanks.   Happy New Year

Comment: You're welcome. I'm American and I always use "towards", but Americans seem to lean more **towards** "toward". I don't know why I lean towards "towards". It's not as if Americans didn't use "towards". For every five times this comes up, I'd say Americans use "towards" one time and "toward" four times if you comprehend my math.